# Difference of appearance in plots made with Pandas and Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I was hoping someone could explain to me why the appearance of the plots I made using Pandas and Matplotlib appear different (one appears smoother than the other) even though I used the same data. What exactly is the Pandas plot doing to make the plots appear that way and can it be reproduced using Matplotlib?. The code to reproduce my example is below.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

popt = np.array([[1.69554337e+01, 1.70615696e+01, 1.71468260e+01, 1.72127134e+01,1.72608200e+01, 1.72927965e+01, 1.73103430e+01, 1.73151963e+01,
        1.73091192e+01, 1.72938907e+01, 1.72712978e+01, 1.72431294e+01,1.72111703e+01, 1.71771978e+01, 1.71429792e+01, 1.71102710e+01,
        1.70808190e+01, 1.70562460e+01, 1.70368378e+01, 1.70220237e+01,1.70112236e+01, 1.70038608e+01, 1.69993614e+01, 1.69971533e+01,
        1.69966655e+01, 1.69973276e+01, 1.69985692e+01, 1.69998200e+01,1.70005098e+01, 1.70000679e+01, 1.69979241e+01, 1.69935088e+01,
        1.69862532e+01, 1.69755993e+01, 1.69615103e+01, 1.69447554e+01,1.69261717e+01, 1.69065937e+01, 1.68868536e+01, 1.68677802e+01,
        1.68501994e+01, 1.68349348e+01, 1.68228078e+01, 1.68146395e+01,1.68112515e+01, 1.68134678e+01, 1.68221166e+01, 1.68380333e+01,
        1.68620623e+01, 1.68950609e+01],
       [1.11567259e-04, 8.85445313e-05, 7.40553458e-05, 6.50045595e-05,5.96405082e-05, 5.69591347e-05, 5.63926927e-05, 5.76410252e-05,
        6.05761218e-05, 6.51843358e-05, 7.15266407e-05, 7.97050376e-05,8.98271244e-05, 1.01963204e-04, 1.16092579e-04, 1.32038867e-04,
        1.49399013e-04, 1.67517720e-04, 1.85943486e-04, 2.04473083e-04,2.22929283e-04, 2.41165184e-04, 2.59071237e-04, 2.76580329e-04,
        2.93671022e-04, 3.10369212e-04, 3.26748586e-04, 3.42930375e-04,3.59082923e-04, 3.75421651e-04, 3.92209978e-04, 4.09761827e-04,
        4.28446334e-04, 4.48690656e-04, 4.70691311e-04, 4.94176642e-04,5.18759880e-04, 5.43964220e-04, 5.69214760e-04, 5.93835778e-04,
        6.17055034e-04, 6.38016759e-04, 6.55804664e-04, 6.69475737e-04,6.78104666e-04, 6.80837522e-04, 6.76951918e-04, 6.65919352e-04,
        6.47464096e-04, 6.21612066e-04],
       [8.23150206e-01, 8.37845373e-01, 8.48438528e-01, 8.55705092e-01,8.60227414e-01, 8.62439416e-01, 8.62665436e-01, 8.61152504e-01,
        8.58096954e-01, 8.53666623e-01, 8.48019672e-01, 8.41320672e-01,8.33754128e-01, 8.25535271e-01, 8.16917658e-01, 8.08197085e-01,
        7.99711388e-01, 7.91816079e-01, 7.84656939e-01, 7.78222235e-01,7.72483102e-01, 7.67398142e-01, 7.62915450e-01, 7.58974464e-01,
        7.55507580e-01, 7.52441547e-01, 7.49698620e-01, 7.47197497e-01,7.44854033e-01, 7.42581745e-01, 7.40292123e-01, 7.37894738e-01,
        7.35297180e-01, 7.32405951e-01, 7.29194002e-01, 7.25741048e-01,7.22138326e-01, 7.18479784e-01, 7.14862141e-01, 7.11384760e-01,
        7.08149339e-01, 7.05259452e-01, 7.02819945e-01, 7.00936209e-01,6.99713329e-01, 6.99255101e-01, 6.99662906e-01, 7.01034380e-01,
        7.03461844e-01, 7.07030412e-01]])

Vd = np.array([0.37, 0.38, 0.39, 0.39, 0.4 , 0.41, 0.41, 0.44, 0.44, 0.44, 0.44,
       0.46, 0.46, 0.47, 0.48, 0.48, 0.48, 0.48, 0.49, 0.49, 0.49, 0.49,
       0.5 , 0.5 , 0.5 , 0.5 , 0.51, 0.51, 0.51, 0.51, 0.52, 0.52, 0.53,
       0.53, 0.53, 0.53, 0.53, 0.54, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.56, 0.56, 0.56,
       0.56, 0.57, 0.57, 0.58, 0.59, 0.59])

labels = {'A':'-', 'B':'-', 'C':'-'}

num_params = popt.shape[0]

# First Plot -- Pandas
param_idx = np.round(Vd, 2)
params_df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.asarray(popt.T),
    columns=[i for i in range(num_params)]
    
    )
params_df['Idx'] = param_idx
params_df['Idx'] = params_df["Idx"].astype('category')
fig_params = (
    params_df.plot(
        x="Idx",
        marker="o",
        linestyle="--",
        subplots=True,
        layout=(5, 3),
        figsize=(8, 8),
        rot=45,
        legend=False
    )
    .ravel()[0]
    .get_figure()
)

plt.gcf().set_facecolor("white")
all_axes = plt.gcf().get_axes()
for i, (k, v) in enumerate(labels.items()):
    all_axes[i].set_ylabel(k + " " + "/" + " " + v, rotation=90)
plt.tight_layout()


plt.show()
[![pandas][1]][1]

# Second plot -- Matplotlib
fig_params, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(8, 2), constrained_layout=True)
axs = axs.ravel()

for i, ax in enumerate(axs):
    if i < len(labels):
        ax.semilogy(params_df['Idx'], params_df[i], marker="o", linestyle="--")
        ax.set_ylabel(str(list(labels.keys())[i]) + " / -", rotation=90)    

fig_params.set_facecolor("white")

plt.show()
```

[image: Matplotlib]

Comment: The `pandas` plotting API uses `matplotlib` as the default backend. There is really no point in "doing it manually", and reproducing all the code handled by the API. See [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) and [source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/tree/v2.0.1/pandas/plotting)